# getchar() function

Tags: c, getchar

I am currently trying to count the digits of a number using `getchar()`.

If i do it with getchar (condition to not count the point or comma) and I put a number like 345.234 does it count 6 like 3-4-5-2-3-4 or does it count 4 like 34-5-23-4?

```
i=0
while((c=getchar())!=',' && c!=EOF)
i++;
```

SIMPLE QUESTION
HOW MUCH DOES IT COUNT
345.234 and ctrl+z on the input all at once
Does it count 4
or does it count 6

Comment: why dont you try it yourself?

Comment: Please, post your code.

Comment: Describing what you are doing doesn't get it done. Show your code.

Comment: `getchar()` doesn't count, `getchar()` gets one character.

Comment: How about reading the definition of `getchar`, eg. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/getchar/ ?

Comment: Returns the next character????Are you even reading my question.

Comment: How does this `34,5,23,4` assumption come to your mind?

Comment: Strange community is strange.All asking the code,this guy!!!!!!!!!! Huh, what? I don't understand. – H2CO3 -Useless comment buddy as always

Comment: Dear Lind, it could be the case, people do not understand your question.

Comment: I made changes to my question....Can you read it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` will be incremented for each call to `getchar()` as long as not `EOF` or `','`  is returned.

If you enter `345.234` and then hit Ctrl-Z this would lead to a value of `7` for `i` when leaving the `while` loop.

3 numbers + 1 dot + 3 numbers = 7 characters.

Comment: So it doesnt get the 34,5,23,4.Ok thats what I wanted to know.

Comment: @Lind: Again, just out of curiosity: How do you get the idea it could count two characters as one?

Comment: since a char can take up to 127,I thought it might get 34 instead of 3,4.Seems I was wrong.

Comment: The characters you enter are represented by numbers, even the numbers themself are nothing more then characters. Also any other sign is treated the same way. Each character has a code between 0 and 127. `'0'` is 48, `'1'` is 49, ... `'A'`is 65, `'B` is 66, ..., `'.' ` is 46. This code is read and stored in the variable `c` of your source.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int i=0,c;
    while(EOF!=(c=getchar())){
        if(c != ',' && c != '.' && c!= '\n')
            ++i;
    }
    printf("number count is %d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```